# Use dataframe column as arguments in function - iPython

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new with python and any help would be appreciated!

I have a dataframe with one column with coordinates:

```
gridReference
(190000, 200000)
(560000, 250000)
(560000, 250000)
(560000, 250000)
(560000, 250000)
(560000, 250000)
(320000, 80000)
```

I also have a function which converts the coordinates to lat long positions 
`toConvert(E,N)` - I am trying to work out how to iterate through the gridReference column and input the values into the toConvert function as arguments then produce the new Lat-Lon coordinates in another dataframe.

Hope that makes sense - Thanks in advance!

Comment: presumably `df['gridReference'].apply(lambda x: toConvert(x[0],x[1]))` should work? otherwise try `df[['gridReference']].apply(lambda x: toConvert(x[0],x[1]), axis=1)`

Comment: It would be in your interest to post some details about `toConvert`.  It may be possible that the transformation you're attempting could be vectorized and executed much more quickly than using `apply`.

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much!

Comment: which worked? the first code snippet or the second?

Answer (score 0):

To answer directly to your question you can do

```
f = lambda x: toConvert(x[0],x[1])    
df['gridReference'].map(f)
```

But actually why do you need a Pandas DataFrame for that? You can just do the same with list of tuples or with tuple of tuples and performance should be the same. 
I believe a column made of tuples is of type object and is not handled by Numpy. Moreorever, your function is not vectorized. You could probably vectorize it using numba (see [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html#vectorize)).

So you can achieve the same without pandas by using [built-in function map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) like so:

```
map(df['gridReference'].values, f)
```